# scala: list as input and output of function

Tags: scala

I am new to scala. I have a very simple problem.

Given a list in python

```
x=[1, 100, "a1", "b1"]
```

I can write a function that will return the last two elements

```
def f(w):
    if w[0]>=1 and w[1]<=100:
    return ([w[2],w[3]])
```

How do I do the equivalent in scala

```
val v= List(1, 100, "a1", "b1")

def g(L:List[Any]): List[String] = {

if( L(0)>=1 &  L(1)<=100 ) {return List(L(2), L(3))}
}

  val w=g(v)
```

This gets me the error

```
  List[Any] = List(1, 100, a, b)
  Incomplete expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a `List[String]` from a `List[Any]`. (Well, you can, but it's a **really** bad thing to do.)

Don't, don't, **don't** create a `List[Any]`. Unlike Python, Scala is a strictly typed language, which means that the compiler keeps a close watch on the type of each variable and every collection. When the compiler looses track of the `List` type it becomes `List[Any]` and you've lost all the assistance the compiler offers to help write programs that don't crash.

To mix types in a collection you can use tuples. Here's the type-safe Scala way to write your `g()` method.

```
def g(tup: (Int,Int,String,String)): List[String] =
  if (tup._1 >= 1 & tup._2 <= 100) List(tup._3, tup._4)
  else List()
```

Usage:

```
val v = (1, 100, "a1", "b1")
val w = g(v)  //w: List[String] = List(a1, b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a typo here:

```
if(L(0)>=1 &  L(1<=100)) {return List(L(2), L(3))}
```

Wouldn't it be like this?

```
if(L(0)>=1 &  L(1)<=100) {return List(L(2), L(3))}
```

The error seems to point out there's something wrong with that extra bracket there.

Comment: yes it was a typo, but now now I have the error . 

List[Any] = List(1, 100, a, b)
 Incomplete expression

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5).takeRight(2)
res44: List[Int] = List(4, 5)
```

You can use a built in function in Scala that does this!